How to make calls to external services in parallel with reactive java
Im using java 17 and I would like to know an efficient way to make calls in parallel using reactive programming.
In the example shown below I have 3 calls to external services. Each one of them fills an object that will be sent in the last call: serviceFour.callServiceFour(resultMap).
@Service
public class ExternalServiceImpl {

    private final ServiceOne serviceOne;
    private final ServiceTwo serviceTwo;
    private final ServiceThree serviceThree;
    private final ServiceFour serviceFour;

    public Mono<String> makeSequentialCalls() {

        Map<String, String> resultMap = new LinkedHashMap<>();

        return serviceOne.callServiceOne()
                .doOnNext(response -> resultMap.put("service1", response))
                .flatMap(response -> serviceTwo.callServiceTwo())
                .doOnNext(response -> resultMap.put("service2", response))
                .flatMap(response -> serviceThree.callServiceThree())
                .doOnNext(response -> resultMap.put("service3", response))
                // Send the response
                .flatMap(response -> serviceFour.callServiceFour(resultMap));
    }
}

The idea is that calls to services 1, 2 and 3 are made in parallel and that finally when they finish, service 4 is called to send the complete response.
Thx.

You can leverage the Mono.zip from Project Reactor
@Service
public class ExternalServiceImpl {

private final ServiceOne serviceOne;
private final ServiceTwo serviceTwo;
private final ServiceThree serviceThree;
private final ServiceFour serviceFour;

public ExternalServiceImpl(ServiceOne serviceOne, ServiceTwo serviceTwo, ServiceThree serviceThree, ServiceFour serviceFour) {
    this.serviceOne = serviceOne;
    this.serviceTwo = serviceTwo;
    this.serviceThree = serviceThree;
    this.serviceFour = serviceFour;
}

public Mono<String> makeParallelCalls() {
    Mono<String> serviceOneResponse = serviceOne.callServiceOne();
    Mono<String> serviceTwoResponse = serviceTwo.callServiceTwo();
    Mono<String> serviceThreeResponse = serviceThree.callServiceThree();

    return Mono.zip(serviceOneResponse, serviceTwoResponse, serviceThreeResponse)
            .flatMap(tuple3 -> {
                Map<String, String> resultMap = new LinkedHashMap<>();
                resultMap.put("service1", tuple3.getT1());
                resultMap.put("service2", tuple3.getT2());
                resultMap.put("service3", tuple3.getT3());

                // Send the combined response to service four
                return serviceFour.callServiceFour(resultMap);
            });
}

}

Hello Souhaila , thanks for your answer, so isn't it necessary to add .parallel() to each of the calls? does it work in parallel anyway?

The concurrency is defined by publisher itself (i.e., the .callServiceX()), and usually if they are IO the are concurrent, so you don't have to do anything special. I.e, you can have as many as you want and all of the them would start making a call once they subscribed.
Note that it's concurrent, not necessary parallel.
You use parallel() for CPU tasks, when you definitely need to spread the load over different CPUs

@Kane i suggest you read up the difference between async and parallel and then try to understand why your usecase does not fit parallel computing and should be done async.
